# I can deploy my app in vmware with win10

Tags: windows

I have one software application for Windows. (Developed for me)
I can share and deploy this application all yet configured over in a Win10 image for Vmware Player?
This is now legal/all right with Windows?
What about license?
The final user can resolve this license (Win10) requirement without problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You mean, you want to distribute a virtual machine running Windows 10?  No, that isn't legal as far as I know.  But check your license from Microsoft, and if in doubt, consult a lawyer.

Comment: Legal questions are [off-topic here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280153/886887).  Try Programmers.SE instead.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Programmers.SE takes *licensing* questions, but general legal questions are off-topic there too. If OP could narrow the question significantly or specify what license(s?) are involved then we might be able to help him.

Comment: @Ixrec: I should think this would be a licensing question, in that it is a question about the licensing terms for Windows.  On the other hand, Windows is licensed under different terms depending on how you purchased it, so I suppose that complicates things.